# SolidColorBrush как Background Строки в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть WPF приложение в котором строки дата грида нужно подсветить в зависимости от содержимого одной ячейки. Для этих целей написал конвертер :

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var cell = value as RecomendedTable;
    if (targetType != typeof(Brush))
    {
        return null;
    }
    if (cell.Advice == "Hold")
    {
        var sb = new SolidColorBrush(new Color() { R = 215, G = 219, B = 97 });
        return sb;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Ничего не происходит, но если вместо `SolidColorBrush` поставить например так:

```
if (cell.Advice == "Hold")
{
    return Brushes.GreenYellow;
}
```

Проблем не возникнет, в чем дело? Как исправить ?

Comment: исключения никакого не возникает в конвертере? поставьте брекпоинт, пройдите пошагово, нормально отрабатывает?

Comment: @Андрей исключений нет

Comment: Подождите, зачем вам конвертер, если у вас используется один и тот же цвет? Просто в ресурсы его нельзя положить?

Comment: @Андрей Цветов 3, я один поставил только для примера

Comment: Ну тогда приводите минимальный пример, который я смогу запустить у себя

Comment: Вопрос уже не актуален?

Comment: @Андрей сам вопрос все еще актуален, только вернуться к нему в ближайшее время не получится.